# redis-commander can't connect to redis service

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, redis

I am trying to set up redis and redis-commander in docker-compose. The redis container is successfully created and started, but in redis-commander I get the following errors:

```
 setUpConnection (R:localhost:6379:0) Redis error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16)

 setUpConnection (R:6379:6379:0) Redis error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.24.235:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16)
```

Here is the setup in docker-compose:

```
redis:
    image: redis:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    command: redis-server --requirepass myPassword
    environment:
      - REDIS_USERNAME=myUsername
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=myPassword
    volumes:
      - cache:/data
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "redis-cli", "ping" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      
  redis-commander:
    image: rediscommander/redis-commander
    depends_on:
      - redis
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOSTS=redis:6379
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=myPassword
      - REDIS_USERNAME=myUsername
        
volumes:
  cache:
  redis:
  redis-commander:
```

I tried different options;

```
- REDIS_HOSTS=redis:6379
- REDIS_HOSTS=127.0.0.1:6379
```

Also explicitly specify the command:

```
redis-server --requirepass myPassword --bind 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating the `REDIS_HOSTS` variable for the `redis-commander` service as follows:

```
environment:
  - REDIS_HOSTS=local:redis:6379
```

The `local` is an alias for the Redis connection, which you can customize if needed.